# python pycassa encoding issue

Tags: python, unicode, pycassa

Having issue encoding issue in inserting data in cassandra using pycassa. The field name is 'text' and content is tweet which can have non-ascii characters. I tried to encode using encode('UTF-8') the text field and it shows, getting converted from 'unicode' to 'str' but still fails? Exact error is here,

```
-'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbf' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128).
-'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\2026' in position 139: ordinal not in range(128).
```

EDIT 1: For field that this is failing in Cassandra, no default validator type has been defined? Could that be a problem? What would cassandra store it as, if type is not specified?

EDIT 2: This answers EDIT 1. Just noticed something, The field where it's failing does not have default type defined and as per doc, cassandra will try to store it as Hex byte arrays (ByteType) where as I am trying to insert UTF-8 encoded string, Could this be a problem?

Traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/opt/socialflow/prod/api-reporting/api-reporting/CassFH/app/c.py", line 40, in send    Mutator.send(self, *a, **kw)  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pycassa/batch.py", line 126, in send    allow_retries=self.allow_retries)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pycassa/pool.py", line 124, in new_f    result = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pycassa/cassandra/Cassandra.py", line 1005, in batch_mutate    self.send_batch_mutate(mutation_map, consistency_level)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pycassa/cassandra/Cassandra.py", line 1013, in send_batch_mutate    args.write(self._oprot)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pycassa/cassandra/Cassandra.py", line 5200, in write    oprot.trans.write(fastbinary.encode_binary(self, (self.**class**, self.thrift_spec)))UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbf' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)[2013-05-20 21:31:14,450] root CRITICAL:

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. So, here was the issue.

- Encoding issue existed in couple of column families for same field called tweet text, which can have non-ascii
  characters.
- I used, pycassa Mutator to batch requests across multiple column families
- So, I fixed encoding issue for 2 column families but failed to do so for rest of 3 CFs.
- So batch insertion fails for all because it failed for 1 in Pycassa batch.
- I recommend 3 thorough reads of python pycassa documentation and cassandra data model.

Hope it will help you all.